# md-input container shows content only after clicking somewhere

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, ng-file-upload

I am using AngularJs 1 and Angular-Material Design. I had built md-input container for a file upload. The problem is, that after selecting a file, it is not shown in the md-input container (selected file is in the ng-files). Only after clicking somewhere the value of the input (in this case the file) is shown. (so the value itself is there actually if I check the value of the field but the name is not shown, only after clicking)

```
<div class="bulk-file-container">
      <md-input-container>
        <input type="file" id="file" ng-files="getFile($files)"/>
      </md-input-container>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.bulk-file-container {
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 33.03rem;
  height: 10.33rem;
  margin: auto;
}
```

This just happened after applying the md-input-container around the input. I have read that other people had similar issues, however, none of their fixed helped me.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

**Edit:**

I inspected the md-input container now and found out that at first (after selecting a file) it gets the class "md-input-focus" and only after clicking somewhere the class "md-input-has-value" appears, which then shows my value.

Comment: `ng-files="getFile($files)"` if this part is removed does it still have the same effect ?

Comment: this part is the value so my file, but if i just put the input field with that it works. However, when putting a md-input-container around it, it does not work anymore

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the model of the input element is only being assigned on the "blur" event, that is when it looses focus. Try adding forcing the update to happen on the change event, it will probably solve your issue:

```
<input type="file" id="file" ng-files="getFile($files)" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'change' }"/>
```

Comment: I tried this and still, the file only appears when I click somewhere